# Delphi parse JSON array or array

Tags: json, delphi

This is the sample JSON I want to be able to parse:

```json
[
  {
    "a":{
      "username":"aaa",
      "email":"aaa@gmail.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "b":{
      "username":"bbb",
      "email":"bbb@gmail.com"
    }
  }
]
```

I need that a call to `getData('b', 'email')` must output `bbb@gmail.com`!

---

I am really struggling to understand how to use the `System.JSON` unit, but I can't get the solution! I want to be able to write a function that extracts a particular data from the above kind of JSON structure. This is my code so far. In the class constructor I have:

```pascal
var
  FIds: TJSONArray;
begin
  FIds := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue({json string here}) as TJSONArray;
end;
```

Then, inside the function that must return the data, I have written this:

```pascal
// 'name' can be 'a' or 'b'  | 'data' can be 'username' or 'email'
function TTest.getData(const name, data: string): string;
var
  FValue, FValueInner: TJSONValue;
begin
  for FValue in Fids do
  begin
    if (FValue is TJSONArray) then
    begin
      //Here I am sure that I have a TJSONArray (which can be 'a' or 'b' from above)
    end;
  end;
end;
```

According to what I have written above, I have to check the value of `name` and decide if I have to access the data inside `a` or `b`. Then, once I have picked the correct JSON array `a` or `b`, I have to select if I want to display the `username` or the `email` field (which is specified inside the `data` variable).

How can I do this?

---

This is my latest attempt but I really can't understand what to do:

```pascal
... same code above ...

if (FValue is TJSONArray) then
begin
  //here I want to check if the current array is a or b
  if ((FValue as TJSONArray).Items[0] as TJSONValue).Value = name then
  begin
    Farr := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(((FValue as TJSONArray).Items[0] as TJSONValue).ToJSON) as TJSONArray;
    try
      //here I want to get the data inside username or email
      for FValueInner in Farr do
        Result := FValueInner.GetValue<string>(data);
    finally
      Farr.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Where `Farr: TJSONArray;` and `FValueInner: TJSONValue;`

Comment: Not an answer, but I gave up a long time ago on using the built-in libraries, and I use `XSuperObject` instead. It's extremely easy to use and very lightweight.

Comment: @JerryDodge well maybe your is the answer. Actually I have read on the doc that there are 3 ways to read JSON and I'm trying to understand something but I don't like them at all and I also find them hard to understand. I don't want to give up but I'll look for that XSuperObject for sure if it's easier!

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi To me it seems that the problem is your understanding of JSON in general, not the System.JSON unit. From what you've written you are treating 'a' and 'b' as arrays but they are OBJECTS and not ARRAYS! An array starts with [ ] but an object starts with { } . If you understand this you'll find that the library is not so difficult at all ;)

Comment: Nothing against this question, but I'm confused again now. How _"Delphi parse JSON array or array"_ can be more searchable than a specific topic asking question? I see no reason to close nor even delete this as it's understandable and answerable question (so as some that are closed and deleted from here).

Comment: Spend some time at http://json.org to learn the terminology

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For new readers looking for these answers.

How about this function, or even simpler if you restructure the JSON data?

```
function getData(JsonString: String; User: String; Field: String): String;
var
  JSonValue: TJSonValue;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
  ArrayElement: TJSonValue;
  FoundValue: TJSonValue;
begin
  Result :='';

  // create TJSonObject from string
  JsonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(JsonString);

  // get the array
  JsonArray := JsonValue as TJSONArray;

  // iterate the array
  for ArrayElement in JsonArray do begin
      FoundValue := ArrayElement.FindValue(User);
      if FoundValue <> nil then begin
        Result := ArrayElement.GetValue<string>(User + '.' + Field);
        break;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

The problem with the sample JSON code above is that it uses the users' names "a" "b" as a *JSON-key* {key:data} for the users' data. In this way you can't use GetValue("a") in your search for data. Structuring your JSON data differently makes the search process a lot easier. I will later on give an example of this.

A way to handle the given JSON data is by using ***FindValue*** so you can check if a field with ***key*** "a" or "b" exists.

```
FoundValue := ArrayElement.FindValue("b");
if FoundValue <> nil then begin
    Result := ArrayElement.GetValue<string>("b"+ '.' + "email");
    break;
```

About the '*parsing a JSON array*' question: After the data is loaded as a TJSonObject you can change the data into a TJSONArray and iterate the elements.

```
  JsonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(JsonString);  
  JsonArray := JsonValue as TJSONArray;
  for ArrayElement in JsonArray do begin
    ...
```

**A working example code for the given JSON data:**

```
unit JsonArray1;

interface

uses System.JSON;

function getData2(JsonString: String; User: String; Field: String): String;
procedure Test1();

implementation

function getData2(JsonString: String; User: String; Field: String): String;
var
  JSonValue: TJSonValue;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
  ArrayElement: TJSonValue;
  FoundValue: TJSonValue;
begin
  Result :='';

  // create TJSonObject from string
  JsonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(JsonString);

  // get the array
  JsonArray := JsonValue as TJSONArray;

  // iterate the array
  for ArrayElement in JsonArray do begin
      FoundValue := ArrayElement.FindValue(User);
      if FoundValue <> nil then begin
        Result := ArrayElement.GetValue<string>(User + '.' + Field);
        break;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure Test1();
var
  DataBase: String;
  EmailAddress : String;
  Username: String;
begin
  DataBase := '[  {"a" : {"username":"aaa","email":"aaa@gmail.com"}},' +
                 '{"b" : {"username":"bbb","email":"bbb@gmail.com"}}  ]';

  EmailAddress := getData2(DataBase, 'b', 'email');
  Username := getData2(DataBase, 'a', 'username');

end;

end.
```

As already mentioned, restructuring the JSON data with proper keys makes the code to find data more simple. Because there is a 1 on 1 relation between the users' data "a":{}, "b":{} it's easy to introduce a 'user' key. Also adding a 'users' key to the array results in all data having keys.

```
  '{"users" : [{ "user":"a", "username":"aaa","email":"aaa@gmail.com"},' +
              '{ "user":"b", "username":"bbb","email":"bbb@gmail.com"}]}';
```

When you iterate the users, you can now use GetValue with the new "user" key.

```
  if ArrayElement.GetValue<String>('user') = 'b' then begin
    Result := ArrayElement.GetValue<String>('email');
```

By giving the array a key you can now get the array with:

```
JsonArray := JsonValue.GetValue<TJSONArray>('users');
```

**A working example code for the restructured JSON data:**

```
unit JsonArray2;

interface

uses System.JSON;

function getData2(JsonString: String; User: String; Field: String): String;
procedure Test2();

implementation

function getData2(JsonString: String; User: String; Field: String): String;
var
  JSonValue: TJSonValue;
  JsonArray: TJSONArray;
  ArrayElement: TJSonValue;
  FoundValue: TJSonValue;
begin
  Result :='';

  // create TJSonObject from string
  JsonValue := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(JsonString);

  // get the array
  JsonArray := JsonValue.GetValue<TJSONArray>('users');

  // iterate the array
  for ArrayElement in JsonArray do begin
      if ArrayElement.GetValue<String>('user') = User then begin
        Result := ArrayElement.GetValue<String>(Field);
        break;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure Test2();
var
  DataBase: String;
  EmailAddress : String;
  Username: String;
begin
  DataBase := '{"users" : [{ "user":"a", "username":"aaa","email":"aaa@gmail.com"},' +
                          '{ "user":"b", "username":"bbb","email":"bbb@gmail.com"}]}';

  EmailAddress := getData2(DataBase, 'b', 'email');
  Username := getData2(DataBase, 'a', 'username');

end;

end.
```

Comment: FYI. In Delphi 10.2, `TJSONValue.FindValue` is a protected function.

Answer (score 7):

Your JSON is an array of objects, so `FIds` is a `TJSONArray` containing `TJSONObject` elements.  And the `a` and `b` fields of those objects are themselves objects, not arrays.  So `FValue is TJSONArray` will always be false while enumerating that array.

Also, `(FValue as TJSONArray).Items[0] as TJSONValue).Value = name` is wrong, because a JSON object contains name/value pairs, but you are ignoring the names, and you are trying to enumerate the pairs as if they are elements of an array when they are really not.  If you want to enumerate an object's pairs, use the [`TJSONObject.Count`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Count) and [`TJSONObject.Pairs[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Pairs) property.  But that is not necessary in this situation since you are looking for a specific pair by its name.  `TJSONObject` has a [`Values[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.JSON.TJSONObject.Values) property for that very purpose.

And `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(((FValue as TJSONArray).Items[0] as TJSONValue).ToJSON) as TJSONArray` is just plain ridiculous.  There is no reason to convert an object back to a JSON string just to parse it again.  It has already been parsed once, you don't need to parse it again.

And lastly, `FValueInner.GetValue<string>(data)` is wrong, because `TJSONValue` does not have a `GetValue()` method, let alone one that uses Generics.

Now, with that said, try something more like this instead:

```
// 'name' can be 'a' or 'b'  | 'data' can be 'username' or 'email'
function TTest.getData(const name, data: string): string;
var
  FValue, FValueInner: TJSONValue;
begin
  Result := '';
  for FValue in Fids do
  begin
    if (FValue is TJSONObject) then
    begin
      FValueInner := TJSONObject(FValue).Values[name];
      if FValueInner <> nil then
      begin
        if (FValueInner is TJSONObject) then
        begin
          FValueInner := TJSONObject(FValueInner).Values[data]; 
          if FValueInner <> nil then
            Result := FValueInner.Value;
        end;
        Exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What I don't understand is when I have to use the TJSONObject and the TJSONValue. I have read the doc more than once but still I have some doubts. Is the TJSONValue the item inside the array and the TJSONObject a generic object? (array or item)

Comment: `TJSONValue` is a base class that all of the other JSON value classes derive from, like `TJSONObject`. You can have an array of strings, an array of integers, an array of objects, etc.  And a JSON object contains name/value pairs that can be arrays, integers, strings, objects, etc. So, everything in the API is exposed as general `TJSONValue` pointers, which you can then type-cast to access specific types of data as needed...

Comment: ... In this case, you have an array of `TJSONValue` pointing at `TJSONObject` instances. Which have an `a` or `b` field that is a `TJSONPair` containing a `TJSONValue` pointing at a `TJSONObject` instance.  Which has a `username` or `email` field that is a `TJSONPair` containing a `TJSONValue` pointing at a `TJSONString`.

Answer (score 2):

if you use [Alcinoe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/) TalJsonDocument  it's will be simple as this :

```
aJsonDoc := TalJsonDocU.create;
aJsonDoc.loadFromFile(...);
for i := 0 to aJsonDoc.node.childnodes.count-1 do begin
  myValue := aJsonDoc.node.childNodes[i].getchildNodeValueText(['b', 'email']); 
  if myValue <> '' then break;
end;
```