# Read value from JSON object in Delphi

Tags: json, delphi

```
[
    {
        "Id": "689202118396696363",
        "RawText": "",
        "Text": "",
        "HasFileLinks": 1,
        "FileLinks": [
            {
                "Id": "689202380389710818",
                "Directory": "\\\\192.168.100.100\\Data\\",
                "Filename": ".\\fileread.pdf",
                "IsDefault": true,
                "IsGenerated": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Hello, please help, I have this JSON data from RestResponse and I'm struggling to read "Filename" value which is "fileread.pdf" and assign it to FN which, I suppose, have to be a string.
I tried so many different examples from internet that, now I am completely confused.
I can read only data ID, Rawtext, Text, HasFilelinks, but I don't know how to read data from "FileLinks": ID, Directory, Filename, isDefault, isGenerated.

Comment: Did you had a look at the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536434/parsing-json-array-in-delphi

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to list all Filename values in a TMemo:

```
const
    JSONSource : String =
            '[' +
            '    {' +
            '        "Id": "689202118396696363",' +
            '        "RawText": "",' +
            '        "Text": "",' +
            '        "HasFileLinks": 1,' +
            '        "FileLinks": [' +
            '            {' +
            '                "Id": "689202380389710818",' +
            '                "Directory": "\\\\192.168.100.100\\Data\\",' +
            '                "Filename": ".\\fileread.pdf",' +
            '                "IsDefault": true,' +
            '                "IsGenerated": false' +
            '            }' +
            '        ]' +
            '    }' +
            ']';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    JSONArray    : TJSONArray;
    ArrayElement : TJSONValue;
    RowValue     : TJSONValue;
    RowItem      : TJSONValue;
    HasFileLinks : Integer;
    FileName     : String;
begin
    Memo1.Clear;
    JSONArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONSource) as TJSONArray;
    try
        for ArrayElement in JSONArray do begin
            if ArrayElement.TryGetValue('HasFileLinks', HasFileLinks) then begin
                if HasFileLinks > 0 then begin
                    RowValue := (ArrayElement as TJSONObject).GetValue('FileLinks');
                    if RowValue is TJSONArray then begin
                        for RowItem in TJSONArray(RowValue) do begin
                            if RowItem.TryGetValue('Filename', FileName) then
                                Memo1.Lines.Add('FileName="' + FileName + '"');
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    finally
        JSONArray.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Hello, where from are + signs in JSON text? When I read JSON data from server there is no + signs in it.

Comment: The '+' is just Delphi to concatenate the string constants required to build the complete JSON and still let it readable in the source code. Delphi compiler will produce JSONString as a string with those '+' nor the single quotes. It is like S := 'abc' + 'def'; which is the same as S:= 'abcdef';

Comment: Many many thanks to fpiette everything works now.