# Deserialize JSON into array of typed objects (Delphi 11)

Tags: json, delphi

I'm attempting to deserialize a JSON response from a web service.  The response is in the form of an array of well-typed objects.  As an example, I'm using songster.com.

In the following (excerpted) code, clearly `TSongsterResponse` is not correct, since I'm getting a collection back.  But neither `array of TSongsterResponse` nor `TSongsterList` will compile.

```
interface

type
  TSongsterResponse = class
    public
      id: integer;
      title: string;
  end;

type TSongsterList = array of TSongsterResponse;

implementation

procedure Sample(AJson: string);
begin
  // What goes here to get an array of TSongsterResponse?
  FSomething :=   TJson.JsonToObject<?????>(RESTResponse1.Content);
end;
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried to follow that example, but I'm hoping to get a typed object from each array value, and that example is extracting a string value from a generic TJsonObject.  I can't see how to modify the inner loop to produce a TSongsterResponse for each array item.

Comment: see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 2):

`TJson.JsonToObject()`, as its name suggests, requires an object type, not an array type. It has a Generic constraint of `class, constructor`, which means it must be able to `Create` an object to deserialize into. It can't deserialize a JSON array that is not inside of a JSON object.

You might try wrapping `RESTResponse1.Content` with `'{...}'`, otherwise you will likely just have to resort to using `TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue()` instead and build up the `TSongsterList` manually yourself (see [Delphi parse JSON array or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534011/)).

It would help to see the actual JSON being parsed, but there is nothing stopping you from defining your own class types to copy the JSON values into.  For example:

```pascal
interface

type
  TSongsterResponse = class
  public
    id: integer;
    title: string;
  end;

  TSongsterList = array of TSongsterResponse;

implementation

uses
  System.JSON;

var
  FSomething: TSongsterList;

procedure Sample(AJson: string);
var
  Value: TJSONValue;
  Arr: TJSONArray;
  Obj: TJSONObject;
  Song: TSongsterResponse;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Value := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(AJson);
  if Value = nil then Exit;
  try
    Arr := Value as TJSONArray;
    SetLength(FSomething, Arr.Count);
    for I := 0 to Arr.Count-1 do
    begin
      Obj := Arr[I] as TJSONObject;
      Song := TSongsterResponse.Create;
      try
        Song.id := (Obj.GetValue('id') as TJSONNumber).AsInt;
        Song.title := Obj.GetValue('title').Value;
        FSomething[I] := Song;
      except
        Song.Free;
        raise;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Value.Free;
  end;
  // use FSomething as needed...
end;
...
Sample(RESTResponse1.Content);
```

That being said, do note that `TRESTResponse` has a [`JSONValue`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTResponse.JSONValue) property that can parse the received JSON content for you, eg:

```pascal
interface

type
  TSongsterResponse = class
  public
    id: integer;
    title: string;
  end;

  TSongsterList = array of TSongsterResponse;

implementation

uses
  System.JSON;

var
  FSomething: TSongsterList;

procedure Sample(AJson: TJSONValue);
var
  Arr: TJSONArray;
  ...
begin
  Arr := AJson as TJSONArray;
  // process Arr same as above...
  // use FSomething as needed...
end;
...
Sample(RESTResponse1.JSONValue);
```

Comment: Why was this answer not accepted? Doing so makes it clear to others that it works (it's Remy, so of course it works).